# why the system hang when I write characters to my dummy character device?

Tags: linux, driver, device, freeze

I am learning how to write Linux Device Driver.
I wrote a dummy character device driver, implemented open, release, write, read in fops;
When I read from device , everything was ok;
When I wrote to device by "echo xx > ", the OS was hang.
Even I comment out all codes in write function except pr_alert and return statements, It still hangs;
Could anybody  help me figure it out?

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/mutex.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/string.h>

struct hello_dev
{
    char *buffer;
    int length;
    dev_t dev;
    struct mutex lock;
    struct cdev *pcdev;
};

struct hello_dev *pHelloDev;

int open_device(struct inode *pinode, struct file *filp)
{

    filp->private_data = pHelloDev;

    return 0;
}

int close_device(struct inode *pinode, struct file *filp)
{
    struct hello_dev *pDev = filp->private_data;

    if (pDev->buffer != NULL)
        kfree(pDev->buffer);

    pDev->buffer = NULL;

    return 0;
}

ssize_t read_device(struct file *filp, char __user *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *loff)
{
    pr_alert("read\n");

    struct hello_dev *pDev = filp->private_data;

    mutex_lock(&pDev->lock);
    if (pDev->buffer == NULL)
    {
        mutex_unlock(&pDev->lock);
        return 0;
    }

    int length = strlen(pDev->buffer);

    // offset max than strlen in buffer, return
    if (*loff > (length - 1))
    {
        mutex_unlock(&pDev->lock);
        return 0;
    } else {

        // available to read
        int len2read = length - *loff;

        if (len < len2read)
        {// buffer length less than available data
            len2read = len;
        }

        int read = copy_to_user(buffer, pDev->buffer + *loff, len2read);
        if (read)
        {

            *loff = *loff + read;
            mutex_unlock(&pDev->lock);
            return read;
        } else {

            *loff = *loff + len2read;
            mutex_unlock(&pDev->lock);
            return len2read;
        }
    }
}

ssize_t write_device(struct file *filp , const char __user *buffer, size_t len, loff_t* loff) {

    pr_alert("write %s\n", buffer);

    // struct hello_dev *pDev = filp->private_data;

    // mutex_lock(&pDev->lock);

    // if(pDev->buffer == NULL) {

    //  pDev->buffer = kmalloc(100, GFP_KERNEL);
    //  pDev->length = 100;
    // }

    // copy_from_user(pDev->buffer, buffer, len);

    // *loff = *loff + len;

    // mutex_unlock(&pDev->lock);

    return len;
}

struct file_operations fops = {
    .open = open_device,
    .release = close_device,
    .read = read_device,
    .write = write_device
};

int init_device(void)
{

    pr_alert("init device\n");

    pHelloDev = kmalloc(sizeof(struct hello_dev), GFP_KERNEL);
    pHelloDev->buffer = NULL;
    pHelloDev->length = 0;

    int ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&pHelloDev->dev, 0, 1, "hello");

    if (ret)
        goto alloc_error;

    if (pHelloDev == NULL)
        goto kmalloc_error;

    pHelloDev->pcdev = cdev_alloc();

    pHelloDev->pcdev->ops = &fops;

    mutex_init(&pHelloDev->lock);

    ret = cdev_add(pHelloDev->pcdev, pHelloDev->dev, 1);

    if (ret)
        goto cdev_add_error;

    return 0;

alloc_error:
    pr_alert("alloc_chrdev_region error, %d\n", ret);
    return ret;

kmalloc_error:
    pr_alert("alloc struct hello_dev error");
    return -ENOMEM;

cdev_add_error:
    pr_alert("cdev_add error, %d\n", ret);
    return ret;
}

void cleanup_device(void)
{

    pr_alert("unload ko\n");

    cdev_del(pHelloDev->pcdev);

    unregister_chrdev_region(pHelloDev->dev, 1);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

module_init(init_device);
module_exit(cleanup_device);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found why write to device hangs.

```
 //this statements has problem
 //maybe there is no \0 in buffer
 //so I print it out, it will hang
 //I wrote a program to write something to device
 //and used strace to trace system call made by this program
 //and found it hangs at write(...) system call
 //and there was nothing printed out
 //so, it must be this statement causing the problem
 //when I removed this statement, everything was ok 
 pr_alert("write %s\n", buffer);
```